# ActiveAndroid not supporting byte[]?

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

Since it is faster to save Bitmaps as byte[] rather than as String in the database, I was trying to do that for my project. However it seems that byte[] are not supported by ActiveAndroid. Here is my code (the columns are not created -> yes I had them as String before, but I reinstalled my App to make sure that this won't cause any trouble):

```
@Table(name = "Image")
public class Image extends Model {
@Column(name = "Image_data")
public byte[] imageData;

@Column(name = "Thumbnail_data")
public byte[] thumbnailData;

public Day day() {
    return (Day)getMany(Day.class,"Day").get(0);
}

public Image(byte[] imageData, byte[] thumbnailData) {
    super();
    this.imageData = imageData;
    this.thumbnailData = thumbnailData;
}

public Image() {
    super();
}

}
```

I am using the beta version of ActiveAndroid (downloaded as .jar):

```
compile files('libs/activeandroid-3.1-beta.jar')
```

I thought that using the beta version could cause this problem so I changed my build.gradle as it is shown on their [github page](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Getting-started):

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I hope it is possible to store byte[] as BLOB in ActiveAndroid.

Answer (score 2):

I have just found a working solution. Just convert the byte[] to a String, save it to the database and once you need it convert the String back to a byte[]:

```
@Table(name = "Image")
public class Image extends Model {

@Column(name = "Image_data")
public String imageData;

@Column(name = "Thumbnail_data")
public String thumbnailData;

public Day day() {
    return (Day)getMany(Day.class,"Day").get(0);
}

public Image(byte[] imageData, byte[] thumbnailData) {
    super();
    this.imageData = Base64.encodeToString(imageData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    this.thumbnailData = Base64.encodeToString(thumbnailData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

public Image() {
    super();
}

public byte[] getImageBytes() {
    return Base64.decode(imageData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

public byte[] getThumbnailBytes() {
    return Base64.decode(thumbnailData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
}
```